# How to set active header/footer type in existing Excel sheet with openpyxl in Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a large number of Excel sheets that I want to iterate through and update the first-page footer and set the worksheet to "Different first page"  on them using openpyxl. The following code works to open the excel file, alter the first-page footer but I cannot find in the docs how to change which footer is the active one for printing. Is this even possible?

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.header_footer.html

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

filename = '150913M2_IS.xlsm'

wb = load_workbook(filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)

ws = wb.active

#Attempted setting this value to True but this does nothing
ws.differentFirst = True

#This works perfectly to set the first page footer
#but I have to manually go in and change the Excel sheet 
#to 'Different first page'
ws.firstFooter.left.text = 'Hello World'

wb.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: set active header/footer type

- [HeaderFooter](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.header_footer.html)
- [HeaderFooterItem](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.header_footer.html#openpyxl.worksheet.header_footer.HeaderFooterItem)

> **class _HeaderFooterPart:**
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, text=None, font=None, size=None, color=None):
>     self.text = text
>     self.font = font
>     self.size = size
>     self.color = color
> ```

---

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.HeaderFooter.differentFirst = True
ws.HeaderFooter.firstFooter.left.text = 'Hello World'

print(ws.HeaderFooter.firstFooter.left.text)
>>> Hello World

# wb.save(<File Name>)
```

***Tested with Python 3.6 - `openpyxl` 3.0.0***